# Saving an external HTML canvas element as an image

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I am trying to access the content of a HTML canvas element (external website) and save it as an image. The website seems to populate the canvas using JavaScript, and I only want to save the finished picture.
[Webpage I'm trying to get the image from](https://raidplan.io/plan/3dAPviff43oX-duC)

The canvas element I want to save as an image:

```
<canvas id="plan_view" class="lower-canvas" width="1108" height="623" style="width: 1108px; height: 623.25px;"></canvas>
```

I have tried using `WebSocket` (C#) to download the HTML content of the page, but this doesn't work since the canvas is populated using JavaScript and I only need the finished canvas.

Is there a way to download the finished canvas element as a picture?